# Python for Android: No project.properties file

Tags: kivy

While in `python-for-android/dist/default`, calling

```
./build.py --dir ../../../kivy/ --package org.example.myapp --name 'MyApp' --version 0.1 debug
```

has provoked:

```
BUILD FAILED
../python-for-android/dist/default/build.xml:6: Source resource does not exist: ../python-for-android/dist/default/project.properties
```

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like your distribution didn't build properly. You'll need to post the output from running `./distribute.sh ...`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ev3nsyy0duajp0z/distribute.log?dl=0